# How to store salts created for hashing in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, security, hash

I have been looking around, and there seems to be many different ways in order to safely store passwords, some more popular than others. Assuming I do not use things like crypt() which does all the work for me in a sense, how should I store the salts randomly generated to be used with sha256 or sha512? I thought about how this can be done, but I am stuck on how this can work effectively. Storing them all in a database and having to use them all seems inefficient. I am curious to know if there is actually a method that is normally used, or if this is really the only way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the salt is stored with the password hash, either in the same column or in an adjacent column.  There is nothing inefficient about this.  Using separate salts for each password is what makes your password system robust.

Comment: Well I understand. But if they have the salt, wouldn't it make it easier to brute force? With the salt at hand, all that would need to be done is add the salt with whatever is being used to brute force it. I assumed it would make more sense to store it in a separate table with all the salts.

Comment: @Andy: How would putting it in a separate table make it more secure? The salt isn't supposed to be secret; it's simply supposed to provide an effectively unique hashing function per user. The way to prevent brute force attacks is to use a slow hashing function like bcrypt.

Comment: @Andy, Having the salt makes it no easier to find a data needed to collide with the hash.  The same number-crunching still has to occur.  Salting each password separately only means that if they were to find a collision and use it to get into your site, they only have one account, not all of them.  Having the salt doesn't help... it only matters that the salt was used when generating the hash.

Comment: Not connecting that salt to a specific password. That was my assumption at least. But it also explains why I believed it was costly. For example, I didn't see why everyone says add a salt if the salt will be readily available either with the password or in the same table/database (assuming it is compromised). If thats the case, yes, it makes it more annoying, but not by much. Thats what I am confused about. I thought a salt was suppose to make it more random as to not allow bruteforcing. But if they can use it while trying to crack it, whats the point?

Comment: @Andy, The point of a salt is so that it is harder to find a match to it in a rainbow table.  If you have 100 users in your database that have the password of `password`, and you're using simple un-salted MD5, they will all have the salt of `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`.  If you look this up in a rainbow table, say the one at http://md5.thekaine.de/, you'll see it.  Now if the password was `passwordjiowfeij23$@I#J23jr][`, the hash is `706273cc2feb9b7eaeed24bcc950e82f`, and if you try to look that up, you won't find it in the rainbow table.

Comment: @Andy, Brute-forcing can definitely still occur, no matter what.  But, it will be a real hassle and will take hundreds of years (if you use a good hash algorithm, like whirlpool).  Adding the salt avoids rainbow tables.  That's all.  Even if you know the hash and salt used, it doesn't help you with the rainbow table.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I guess my interpretation of what a salt was has been wrong. Thank you very much for clearing that up!

Comment: No problem.  Also, this article may help:  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe/